# Improper complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate $\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{e^{a+ix}}{(a+ix)^b}dx$ where $a>1$ and $b>0.$

I've tried looking at $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z}$ and integrating around a rectangular contour surrounding the singularity at $z=0$, where the parametrization of one of the side lengths was exactly the integral in question, but I had a hard time calculating the residue at 0 because $b$ is not necessarily an integer.

I also think that maybe the contour should've been a keyhole, since we'll need a branch of the logarithm to even consider $z^b = e^{b\log z}$, but then I confused myself even more. Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: u=a+ix and then pull i out of integral and then use integration by parts

Comment: This is not "indefinite".  Perhaps you meant "improper"?

Comment: You're correct, it should be improper. I've edited the title

Comment: $dz\equiv dx$ right?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\left.
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{a + \ic x} \over \pars{a + \ic x}^{b}}\,\dd x\,
> \right\vert_{\ a\ >\ 1\,,\ b\ >\ 0}:\ {\large ?}}$.

\begin{align}
&\left.
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{a + \ic x} \over \pars{a + \ic x}^{b}}\,\dd x\,
\right\vert_{\ a\ >\ 1\,,\ b\ >\ 0}
\,\,\,\stackrel{a\ +\ \ic x\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
-\ic\int_{a - \infty\ic}^{a + \infty\ic}x^{-b}\expo{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] &\
\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}\,\,\,
\ic\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}\pars{-x}^{-b}\expo{-\pi b\ic}\expo{x}\,\dd x +
\ic\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}\epsilon^{-b}\expo{-\ic b\theta}\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic
\,\dd\theta +
\ic\int_{-\epsilon}^{-\infty}\pars{-x}^{-b}\expo{\pi b\ic}\expo{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\ic\expo{-\pi b\ic}\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}x^{-b}\expo{-x}\,\dd x -
{2\epsilon^{1 - b}\sin\pars{b\pi} \over b - 1} -
\ic\expo{\pi b\ic}\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}x^{-b}\expo{-x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
2\sin\pars{b \pi}\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}x^{-b}\expo{-x}\,\dd x -
{2\epsilon^{1 - b}\sin\pars{b\pi} \over b - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
2\sin\pars{b \pi}\bracks{%
{\epsilon^{1 - b}\expo{-\epsilon} \over b - 1} -
\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}{x^{-b + 1} \over -b + 1}\pars{-\expo{-x}}\,\dd x} -
{2\epsilon^{1 - b}\sin\pars{b\pi} \over b - 1}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim} & \,\,\,
-\,{2\sin\pars{b \pi} \over b - 1}
\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}{x^{-b + 1}}\expo{-x}\,\dd x
\end{align}

> The last integral converges, in the $\ds{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}$-limit, whenever
>   $\ds{\Re\pars{-b + 1} > - 1 \implies \Re\pars{b} < 2}$.

In such a case,
\begin{align}
&\left.
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{a + \ic x} \over \pars{a + \ic x}^{b}}\,\dd x\,
\right\vert_{\ a\ >\ 1\,,\ b\ >\ 0} =
-\,{2\sin\pars{b \pi} \over b - 1}\,\Gamma\pars{-b + 2}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{2\sin\pars{b \pi} \over b - 1}\,
{\pi \over \Gamma\pars{b - 1}\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{b - 1}}} =
\bbx{\ds{2\pi \over \Gamma\pars{b}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I will give two proofs for this integral. One of them realizes the integral as an inverse Laplace transform of $\displaystyle \frac{t^{b-1}}{\Gamma(b)}$ valued at $t = 1$, and the other is a direct computation of a contour integral (I feel this is what @Felix Marin was communicating, but I may be wrong).

**Proof 1**
Consider the Laplace transform of $\displaystyle \frac{t^{b-1}}{\Gamma(b)}$; we have

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}\left(\frac{t^{b-1}}{\Gamma(b)}\right)(s) = \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{b-1}}{\Gamma(b)}e^{-st} \, dt = s^{-b}.
\end{align*}

Then the inverse Laplace transform (i.e. Bromwich integral) gives

$$2\pi i\mathcal{L}^{-1}(s^{-b})(t) = \int_{a - i\infty}^{a+i\infty} s^{-b}e^{st} \, ds = 2\pi i\frac{t^{b-1}}{\Gamma(b)} ,$$
where $a$ is chosen such that the path of integration allows $s^{-b}$ to be defined (i.e. $s^{-b}$ is assumed to be the principal branch with a branch point at $s = 0$, so with $a > 1$, we have the desired circumstance). We have

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{a+ix}}{(a+ix)^b} \, dx &= -i\int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty} s^{-b}e^{s} \, ds \\
&=2\pi \mathcal{L}^{-1}(s^{-b})(1) \\
&= \frac{2\pi}{\Gamma(b)},
\end{align*}
as desired.

**Proof 2** Let $R > 0$ be large and $r > 0$ be small. Let $f(z) = z^{-b}e^z$, where $z^{-b} = e^{-b\log z}$ is assumed to be the principal branch. Consider the following contour, which we will denote as $\gamma$: a segment centered at $a$ running from $a-iR$ to $a+iR$, a circular arc centered $a$ running from $a+iR$ to $a-\sqrt{R^2-\epsilon^2}+i\epsilon$, a line segment running from $a-\sqrt{R^2-\epsilon^2}+i\epsilon$ to $-\sqrt{r^2-\epsilon^2}+i\epsilon$, a circular arc centered at $z = 0$ running from $\pi-\arcsin(\epsilon/r)$ to $-\pi+\arcsin(\epsilon/r)$, a line segment running from $-\sqrt{r^2-\epsilon^2}-i\epsilon$ to $a-\sqrt{R^2-\epsilon^2}-i\epsilon$, and then a circular arc running from $a-\sqrt{R^2-\epsilon^2}-i\epsilon$ to $a-iR$.

We have

\begin{align*}
\int_\gamma f &= i\int_{-R}^{R}f(a+it) \, dt + \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi-\arcsin(\epsilon/R)} f(a+Re^{i\theta})iRe^{i\theta} \, d\theta \\
& +\int_{a-\sqrt{R^2-\epsilon^2}}^{-\sqrt{r^2-\epsilon^2}} f(t+i\epsilon) \, dt 
+ \int_{\pi-\arcsin(\epsilon/r)}^{-\pi+\arcsin(\epsilon/r)} f(re^{i\theta})ire^{i\theta} \, d\theta \\
&+\int_{-\sqrt{r^2-\epsilon^2}}^{a-\sqrt{R^2-\epsilon^2}} f(t-i\epsilon) \, dt +\int_{-\pi+\arcsin(\epsilon/R)}^{-\pi/2} f(a+Re^{i\theta})iRe^{i\theta} \, d\theta.
\end{align*}

Since $f$ is analytic in the interior of $\gamma$, Cauchy's integral theorem gives $\displaystyle \int_\gamma f = 0$. Consider the upper large arc; we have

\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi-\arcsin(\epsilon/R)} \frac{e^{a+Re^{i\theta}}}{(a+Re^{i\theta})^b}iRe^{i\theta} \, d \theta\right| &= \left|-\int_{0}^{\pi/2-\arcsin(\epsilon/R)} \frac{e^{a+iRe^{i\theta}}}{(a+iRe^{i\theta})^b}Re^{i\theta} \, d \theta\right| \\
&=\left|Re^a\int_{0}^{\pi/2-\arcsin(\epsilon/R)} \frac{e^{i\cos\theta}e^{-R\sin \theta}}{((a-R\sin\theta)+iR\cos\theta)^b}e^{i\theta} \, d \theta\right| \\
&\leq Re^a \int_{0}^{\pi/2-\arcsin(\epsilon/R)} \frac{e^{-R\sin \theta}}{|(a-R\sin\theta)+iR\cos\theta|^b} \, d \theta \\
&=Re^a \int_{0}^{\pi/2-\arcsin(\epsilon/R)} \frac{e^{-R\sin \theta}}{\sqrt{a^2-2aR\sin \theta+R^2}^b} \, d \theta \\
&\leq Re^a \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{e^{-R\sin \theta}}{\sqrt{a^2-2aR\sin \theta+R^2}^b} \, d \theta \\
&\leq \frac{e^a}{|R-a|^b} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} Re^{-R\sin \theta} \, d \theta \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (1)
\end{align*}
Let $\delta > 0$ be arbitrarily small. Partition the integral in $(1)$ over $(0, \delta)\cup (\delta, \pi/2-\delta) \cup (\pi/2-\delta, \pi/2)$ so that we have
\begin{align*}
& \frac{e^a}{|R-a|^b} \left(\int_{0}^{\delta} + \int_{\delta}^{\pi/2-\delta} + \int_{\pi/2-\delta}^{\pi/2} \right) Re^{-R\sin \theta} \, d \theta \\
 &= \frac{e^a}{|R-a|^b} \left(\int_{0}^{\delta} R(e^{-R\cos \theta}+e^{-R\sin \theta}) \, d \theta + \int_{\delta}^{\pi/2-\delta} Re^{-R\sin \theta} \, d \theta\right)  \\
&\leq \frac{e^a}{|R-a|^b} \left(2\int_{0}^{\delta} Re^{-R\cos \theta} \, d \theta + \int_{\delta}^{\pi/2-\delta} Re^{-R\sin \theta} \, d \theta\right) \\
&\leq \frac{e^a}{|R-a|^b} \left(2\delta\sup_{\theta \in (0,\delta)}Re^{-R\cos \theta} + \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\delta\right)\sup_{\theta \in (\delta, \pi/2-\delta)} Re^{-R\sin \theta} \right) \\
&= \frac{e^a}{|R-a|^b} \left(2\delta Re^{-R\cos \delta} + \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\delta\right)Re^{-R\sin \delta} \right) \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (2)
\end{align*}

which, for large $R$, gives that $(2)$ will tend to zero. Thus, the integral over the large arc will tend to zero as $R \to \infty$. A similar analysis can be done for the integral over the lower large arc.

FelixMarin has observed the behavior of the integral at the line segments and the smaller arc, so I will leave it at that.